# retina design with css for google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am designing a website with images for retina. It works good with safari on macbook pro and iphone. But with Chrome version 24.0 on a macbook pro with Mountain Lion I only see 1/4 of the retina image.

I have a logo with the size 300px x 83px and for retina I have a retina logo with the size 600px x 166px

My code (with doctype html first):

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
.headerlogo {width:300px;height:83px;background: url(logo300.png);
background-size: 300px 83px;padding:0px;margin:0px}


@media  (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
(min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
(min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
(min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {

.headerlogo     {;background: url(logo600.png);}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="headerlogo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried "background-size:100%;" ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a rogue semicolon:

```
.headerlogo     {;background: url(logo600.png);}
```

Should be:

```
.headerlogo     {background: url(logo600.png);}
```

You may have to specify the background-size property again for the retina image too at the larger size.

Try adding "only screen" and see if that helps matters:

```
@media only screen and (-Webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {

        .headerlogo {
            background: url(logo600.png);
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to your page or create a jsfiddle replicating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try "background-size:100%;"
I'm not sure so i put it as a comment but i think you didn't see it.

Comment: Thanks, for trying. But it didnot help.